# I can't remember this question in Valley of Wishes

Tags: ring-fit-adventure

I am in Valley of Wishes, and when I completed River Road, it displayed:

> It's a new day. ... (I can't remember exactly what)

Then, I saw a selection with the choices Yeah and Nah. My hand accidentally clicked on Nah and I never got to see the question. Does anybody know what the question is?